# Find the number x such that the point $C=(x,0)$ achieves the minimum of the function $|AC|+|BC|$

Tags: calculus, geometry

Consider two points $A=(0,5)$ and $B=(10,3)$ in the $xy$-plane. Find the number $x$ such that the point $C=(x,0)$ achieves the minimum of the function $|AC|+|BC|$. Here $|AC|$ denotes the distance between the two points $A$ and $C$, and $|BC|$ denotes the distance between the two points $B$ and $C$.

I don't know how to approach this question... I would assume you have to use the distance formula... but not too sure what to do after that part... Would appreciate it if you could help me out with this question!

Comment: One of the ways is to add the distances and equate the derivative to zero. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Reflect $A$ across the $x$-axis to $A'$. Draw the segment $A'C$; now try to minimize $|A'C| + |CB|$. *Unless you are forced to use Calculus...*

Answer (score 1):

Consider the point $B'(10,-3)$ symmetric of $B$ wrt $x$-axis.

The point $C$ where $AB'$ intersects the $x$-axis is the wanted point.

Indeed any other point $D$ has distances $AD+DB>AB$ for the triangular inequality

Hope this helps
$$...$$

---

[image]

Comment: Holy smokes, what an easy and straightforward way to solve the question! I never would've thought of this.

Comment: @uriyaba This is sadly a common approach to such questions.

Comment: Sadly? Why? It's beautiful..

Answer (score 0):

Using the distance formula, $dist(A,B) = \sqrt{(X_B-X_A)^2+(Y_B-Y_A)^2}$:

$$|AC| = dist(A,C) = \sqrt{(X_C-X_A)^2+(Y_C-Y_A)^2}=\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(0-5)^2} = \sqrt{x^2+25}=(x^2+25)^{0.5}$$

$$|BC| = dist(B,C) = \sqrt{(X_C-X_B)^2+(Y_C-Y_B)^2}=\sqrt{(x-10)^2+(0-3)^2} = (x^2-20x+109)^{0.5}$$

Let $f(x)=|AC|+|BC|= (x^2+25)^{0.5} + (x^2-20x+109)^{0.5}$.

Now, in order to find the minimum of the function, we need to find $f'(x)$ and equate it to $0$.

Using the chain rule:

$$f'(x) = 0.5(x^2+25)^{-0.5}\cdot2x+0.5(x^2-20x+109)^{-0.5}\cdot(2x-20) = \frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+25}}+\frac{2x-20}{2\sqrt{x^2-20x+109}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+25}}+\frac{x-10}{\sqrt{x^2-20x+109}}$$

Now, equate the derivative to $0$ and solve for $x$:

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+25}}+\frac{x-10}{\sqrt{x^2-20x+109}}=0$$

The equation yields two possible $x$ values: $x_1=6.25$ and $x_2=25$.
Note that:

$f(x_1)=f(6.25)=12.806$

$f(x_2)=f(25)=40.792$

Therefore, the correct answer is $x=6.25$.